# According to Pentecostalism, what is the impact of the sin nature, hormones, and the Holy Spirit on libido?

Tags: christian-living, pneumatology, sexuality, pentecostalism

What has more of an affect on libido, the flesh/sin nature or hormones and how does that change, after becoming a Christian filled with The Holy Spirit? And does receiving the Holy Spirit as a teen give you power over the flesh with peak hormones?

I'm interested in the views of the Assemblies of God and other Pentecostals.

Comment: Are you talking about Confirmation or Baptism or what are you asking about specifically?  And who are you asking (Catholics, Mormons, Baptists, etc.) There are many different denominations who participate on this site and we more-or-less try to match up the questions so we can give precise answers.  Please edit your question to make it more specific.

Comment: I guess it's geared more towards Assembly of God, Pentecostals, and other denominations the speak on the Power of the Holy Spirit.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very provocative question and with many unspoken layers. It’s hard not to assume certain things into the question that were not explicitly asked. For instance, “peak hormones” in teenagers doesn’t seem to refer to acne, pubic hair and height increase but rather to emotional stability, sexual self gratification and pornography. This is not an exhaustive list, merely an example and obviously I could be way off. Please correct me if I’m wrong.

This can be a very controversial topic because it is very personal, and in some cases the person in question is experiencing a thought that is not their own.

> “But he turned and **said to Peter**, "Get behind me, **Satan**! You are a hindrance to me. For you are not setting **your mind** on the things of G-d, but on the things of man."”
>   ‭‭Matthew‬ ‭16:23‬ ‭ESV‬‬

Peter is clearly talking but in fact it was satan who had planted the thought into Peter’s head and Peter having no discernment owned the idea and criticized Jesus. Here is another example

> “During supper, when the devil had already put it **into the heart** of Judas Iscariot, Simon's son, to betray him,”
>   ‭‭John‬ ‭13:2‬ ‭ESV‬‬

“Put into the heart”, it when further than the head, it is now at the heart level. A thought that rooted itself deeper.

Often times, bad thinking about G-d can give opportunity to satan and his daimons(demons) to influence someone into certain decisions and even convince them about certain things that are not true. If you don’t have a solid understanding of what G-d actually said, like Eve, you may be tempted to rationalize yourself into a mistake and consequently a sin, which ripples into other people’s lives.

We are body, soul and spirit. The body (flesh) wars against the spirit and the spirit against the flesh.

> “For the desires of the flesh are against the Spirit(spirit), and the desires of the Spirit(spirit) are against the flesh, for these are opposed to each other, **to keep you from doing the things you want to do**.
>   ‭‭Galatians‬ ‭5:17‬ ‭ESV‬‬

When someone is born against they are born again (either that means their spirit is quickened/made alive or they are given a brand new spirit as per Ezekiel) and this spirit cannot sin. It is perfect born of incorruptible seed. The human spirit has access to the Holy Spirit and communes with the Holy Spirit, the hidden things of G-d. However your spirit **cannot** act directly on the body without going through the soul (will, mind and emotions). There is one except where the spirit bypasses the soul and acts on the body directly, and that is speaking in tongues

> “For if I pray in a tongue, my spirit prays but my **mind is unfruitful** (or doesn’t understand).”
>   ‭‭1 Corinthians‬ ‭14:14‬ ‭ESV‬‬

This bypass of the mind prevents the soul from interfering with the message. But for the most part the soul is involved. Now due to sin nature, the flesh has conspired with the soul against the spirit. And that’s why the flesh generally wins against what the spirit wants to do.

> “For I delight in the law of G-d, in my **inner being**(spirit or inner man), but I see in **my members**(flesh) another law waging war against the law of **my mind**(soul) and making me captive to the law of sin that dwells in my members(flesh).”
>   ‭‭Romans‬ ‭7:22-23‬ ‭ESV‬‬

If the issue is not very deep then it is a matter of changing or renewing one’s mind so that the flesh cannot conspire with the mind aganst their spirit.

> “Do not be conformed to this world, but be transformed by the **renewal of your mind**, that by testing you may discern what is the will of G-d, what is good and acceptable and perfect.”
>   ‭‭Romans‬ ‭12:2‬ ‭ESV‬‬

Some people struggle with pornography because they have a wrong thinking. For instance, they don’t believe G-d loves them. When that thinking is addressed and corrected their addiction stops.

Others have left an open door and given opportunity to the devil through wrong information. They don’t know a door needs to be shut because they don’t know something like oral sex is persimissble or not. Because they don’t take a stance on the issue they have an open door. Oral sex **is** wrong as defined by Scripture but recently the words have been translated to exclude the parent definition and it has caused ambiguity.

> **Sodomy** definition anal or **oral** copulation with a member of the opposite sex.

Sodomy is not limited to homosexual but also includes heterosexual copulation and it’s not merely anal but also oral sex. When someone  doesn’t shut a door, like in this case, they can’t take a stance against oral sex, the door stsys open and they can be influenced in their mind to commit actions in your flesh. It doesn’t start in their flesh, **the command comes from the mind and then the hormones change accordingly**.

> “And the peace of G-d, which surpasses all understanding, will guard your **hearts** and your **minds** in Christ Jesus.”
>   ‭‭Philippians‬ ‭4:7‬ ‭ESV‬‬

Guarding of the heart and mind or one’s soul is more important than balancing hormones with pharmaceuticals. Not saying that in some cases as a last resort pharmaceuticals may be needed but it’s not a first resort for a healthy person.

Now there are other factors that can affect the flesh. The flesh can be attacked from the outside or from the inside. From the inside it is most effective, imagine taking a city from outside its walls or from within its walls, the effort is far smaller from within the walks. If someone has opened themselves up to or someone else has opened them up to daimons(demons) then the aforementioned renewing of the mind will not work because there is a deeper issue.

Usually it is a curse. Which is essentially a legal right to exploit. These can come in different ways, rebellion, dabbling in the occult, persistent habitual sin just to name a few. Sometimes a parent or even several generations earlier can have an ongoing curse like alcoholism or adultery. These legal contracts until they are broken will be exploited by the enemy.

And although when you are born again all curses are broken, unless you specifically address the curse these demons that exploit this legal “loop hole” will squat and trespass onto your property. They need to be kicked out. That’s why some things that are stronger like masturbation, homosexual tendencies, eating disorders, phobias, drug/alcohol addictions may need a curse to be broken and those that exploit the curse (daimons) need to be removed from the premises.

I would highly recommend Derek Prince on breaking the curse, just go to YouTube and listen to his sermon, check it with Scripture and then release yourself by praying the prayer at the end.

Don’t go straight to breaking curses and don’t  escalate immediately. Start by renewing your mind, feed yourself with the Scripture get a good understanding of the Word, build the walls of your soul up, so that when the curse is broken and the eviction takes place (if it is necessary) you can maintain the victory and the walls are impenetrable.

If someone cannot donthis for themselves or struggle to get freedom in extreme situations then they will need deliverance by a minister who has this calling on their life and is experience in deliverance. But again, it’s not necessary to escalate to this for people who function normal lives other than their addiction or personal struggle.

Please let me know if this is the angle you were asking your question in or whether I went on a totally different tangent. Thank you and be blessed of G-d. I would add a denomination but although this is somewhat of a Charismatic Pentecostal teaching it isn’t limited to and it has started to be accepted by others too.

If you want to downvote that’s fine, I’m not here for points, I would really like a reason why you think I’m wrong and if you have more questions please ask.

Comment: You make a good point. It's a deep question and I wanted to get people opinions on an answer because I know The Holy Spirit gives Power over sin/since nature where it speaks about being dead to sin and no more a slave to sin but a slave to Christ. I believe God's Grace is more than enough.

Comment: Having power and authority is different from annulling existing contracts. G-d in principle doesn’t overrule the freewill decisión of those who have entered into covenants. The cross of Jesus Christ annulls the power of the contracts/covenants but without intentional action and breaking of these covenants its equivalent to having the right to kick out a squatter but never kicking them out. Generally squatters don’t leave of their own accord. At least that has been my experience.